Solving system of two equations
For $\mu \in (-\infty,-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6})$, I need to solve for $T$ and $\mu$ the system
$$ \frac{1}{2}A =\frac{2T}{\sqrt{-(\frac{\pi^{2}}{3} + 2\mu)}}\arctan{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{-(\frac{\pi^{2}}{3} + 2\mu)}}}$$
and
$$     \frac{1}{2}E =\pi T + \frac{\mu}{2}A
$$
Naively asking Solve to do this does not yield a result. I then considered restricting the domain $\mu \in [-\pi^2,-\pi^2 +\epsilon], \epsilon << 1$ and taking the linear series approximation at $\mu=-\pi^2$ to get  $\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)+\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \left(\mu +\pi ^2\right)}{5 \pi ^2}+O\left(\left(\mu +\pi ^2\right)^2\right)$ and then asking Solve again to do this, but this yielded a very long result that I do not understand.
Simplify[
 Solve[energy/2 == \[Pi]  T + \[Mu]/2 waveaction && 
   waveaction/
    2 == (2  T)/
     Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3 + 2 \[Mu])] (ArcTan[Sqrt[2/3]] + (
       2 Sqrt[2/3] (\[Mu] + \[Pi]^2))/(
       5 \[Pi]^2)), {T, \[Mu]}]]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Usage of Solve should be appropriately  restricted to provide well defined solutions.  You can use e.g. Solve[en/2 == \[Pi] T + \[Mu]/2 wa &&    wa/2 == (2 T)/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3 + 2 \[Mu])] (ArcTan[ Sqrt[2/3]] + (2 Sqrt[2/3] (\[Mu] + \[Pi]^2))/(5 \[Pi]^2)) && \[Mu] < -(Pi^2/ 6) && (en | wa) \[Element] Reals && wa != 0, {T, \[Mu]}, Reals,   Method -> Reduce].   Results are true under quite involved conditions.

More on related issue find here. Instead of Method -> Reduce one can use MaxExtraConditions -> All or use Reduce.

You cannot expect closed analytic formula for this problem. Much simpler problem, say ArcTan[x]*x == 2, cannot be solved either.  So you must be satisfied with numerical answer.

I think there is no simple closed formula for this problem, you should be satisfied with numeric solution. So I will just outline how NSolve can be used.
eq=(A/2==(2 T ArcTan[\[Pi]/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3)-2 \[Mu]]])/Sqrt[-(\[Pi]^2/3)-2 \[Mu]]&&e/2==\[Pi] T+(A \[Mu])/2)


Unknown variables are $T$ and , whereas $A$ and $e$ are given parameters.
First eliminate $T$:
mueq = Eliminate[eq, T]


This is a complicated transcendental equation for , there is no hope of obtaining analytic formula. But
if you give numerical values to the parameters $A$ and $e$, MMA can numerically find . For example,
cond = {A -> 0.2, e -> -10};
musols = NSolve[(mueq /. cond) && \[Mu] < -Pi^2/6, \[Mu], Reals]

(* {{\[Mu] -> -25.0418}} *)

Flatten[Table[Join[musol,#]&/@Solve[eq[[2]] /.cond /.musol, T], {musol,musols}], 1]

(* {{\[Mu] -> -25.0418, T -> -0.794446}} *)

Depending on parameters $A$ and $e$, the number of solutions to mueq may change. For example, there is no solution for cond = {A -> 1, e -> 20}.

Is it possible to range $A$ and $e$ over a region and plot the corresponding pairs $(T,\mu)$ for solutions do exist?

Just by testing different parameters, it seems they cannot share sign

@KZ-Spectra Let F() denote the LHS of mueq. Then F() → 1/12 (6 e Pi + A Pi^3)^2 as  → -Pi^2/6 and F() → 12 A e Pi^2 as  → -∞. So the intermediate value theorem assures you that there is a solution  to F()=0, if A e < 0 and 6 e Pi + A Pi^3 ≠ 0.
